# Polymer Iron Ajax PDF Response - Prevent Chrome Pop-up blocked

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf, download, polymer

I'm using Polymer Iron Ajax to get a PDF document from the server. However, when forcing a download on the client, Chrome (Version 65.0.3325.181) shows the message "Pop-up blocked" - which is not acceptable from a usability point of view. Any ideas how to get around this so the download is not blocked? I've simplified the code below as the PDF is dynamically generated using Puppeteer from data contained in the ajax request.

Server code using Express.js:

```
response.type('application/pdf');
response.attachment('resume.pdf');
response.send(mypdf);

app.listen(8080)
```

Polymer App code:

```
<iron-ajax id="myironajax" method="GET" handle-as="blob" on-response="handlePdfResponse" url="http://localhost:8080/pdf"></iron-ajax>

handlePdfResponse(e) {
    var file = new Blob([e.detail.response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = fileURL;
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.download = 'myfile.pdf';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
  }
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I think that it blocks popups that are not a direct result of a user action. Try to comment out the line that triggers the click event and do it yourself "manually" and if this way it works you will have to re-think the interaction.

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely correct. One solution could be to use a third party such as FileSaver.js, another could be to display a toast stating file is ready with link that allows user to click to download.